# Spring Boot 2.2.1: Disable Logging for inner class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

Log messages from inner classes are ignored when specifying `logging.level` configuration at the package level in application.properties / yaml. At the individual class level, it appears you're supposed to use the [square brackets] convention to wrap the line like so: `package.[OuterClass$InnerClass]` but I can't get it to remove this line from Spring Cloud:

```
INFO 39179 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

I know that line is harmless but it just seems strange to not be able to control this. I've tried a variety of patterns but all of them don't do anything.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.context.support.[PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker]=ERROR
logging.level.[org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker]=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.BeanPostProcessorChecker=ERROR
```

Anyone have a clue if any of these are supposed to work and this is a bug or if there's a new convention I'm unaware of?

Comment: I think the 2nd approach should work. Have you tried DEBUG or INFO level? Maybe it's not an ERROR, but DEBUG or INFO.

Comment: okay my question wasn't clear enough - i'm trying to get rid of that line. i set it to ERROR because i don't want to see any logging unless something bad has happened from that class.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to disable it like you but without any success so I had to disable (change the log level to WARN) the whole package logging.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.context.support=WARN
```

I know it is not the ideal solution but I need to hide it in tests only so it is good for my use case.